# Pandas join multine row text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading pdf using tabula-py.

```py
from tabula import read_pdf
pdf_path = "/home/user/test.pdf"
df = read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all', silent='True')
```

Unfortunately, my pdf formatting is not consistent and the text of one of the colum is split across multiple lines as shown below:

```py
Date        Comment      post_id
----------------------------------
03/07/20    Comment 1           1
03/07/20    Comment b 1         2
NaN         Comment b 2       NaN
NaN         Comment b 3       NaN
04/07/20    Comment c 1         3
NaN         Comment c 1       NaN
```

How can I format data frame to like below

```py
Date        Comment                             post_id
-------------------------------------------------------------
03/07/20    Comment 1                                 1
03/07/20    Comment b 1 Comment b 2 Comment b 3       2
04/07/20    Comment c 1 Comment c 1                   3
```

few more single lines columns which are working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are duplicated `Date` values create helper `Series` with test non missing values with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and pass to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and `join`:

```
g = df['Date'].notna().cumsum()

df = df.groupby(g).agg({'Date':'first', 'Comment': ' '.join}).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
       Date                              Comment
0  03/07/20                            Comment 1
1  03/07/20  Comment b 1 Comment b 2 Comment b 3
2  04/07/20              Comment c 1 Comment c 1
```

For general solution for aggregate first for all columns without `Comment` is possible generate dictionary dynamic:

```
print (df.columns)
Index(['Date', 'Comment', 'post_id'], dtype='object')

g = df['Date'].notna().cumsum()

d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['Comment']), 'first')
d['Comment'] = ' '.join
print (d)
{'Date': 'first', 'post_id': 'first', 
  'Comment': <built-in method join of str object at 0x00000000028761B0>}


df = df.groupby(g).agg(d).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
       Date  post_id                              Comment
0  03/07/20      1.0                            Comment 1
1  03/07/20      2.0  Comment b 1 Comment b 2 Comment b 3
2  04/07/20      3.0              Comment c 1 Comment c 1
```

Similar idea with overwrite `Comment` key in dictionary for same order of columns in output DataFrame:

```
print (df.columns)
Index(['Date', 'Comment', 'post_id'], dtype='object')

g = df['Date'].notna().cumsum()

d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns, 'first')
d['Comment'] = ' '.join
print (d)
{'Date': 'first', 
 'Comment': <built-in method join of str object at 0x00000000028761B0>, 
 'post_id': 'first'}

df = df.groupby(g).agg(d).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
       Date                              Comment  post_id
0  03/07/20                            Comment 1      1.0
1  03/07/20  Comment b 1 Comment b 2 Comment b 3      2.0
2  04/07/20              Comment c 1 Comment c 1      3.0
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems perfect, but unfortunately, single lines columns which are working as expected are missing now. Can you guide me to fix that.

Comment: @silentsudo - There are same values per groups, so need like `.agg({'Date':'first', 'Comment': ' '.join, 'col1':'first', 'col2':'first'})` ?

Comment: Thank for promp response i tried same as you tolf `df = df.groupby(g).agg({'Date':'first', 'Narration': ' '.join, 'post_id':'first'}).reset_index(drop=True)` but it threw `SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported` error

Comment: @silentsudo - hmm, so you need first value per group for all columns without `Comment`, there is used `join` ?

Comment: @silentsudo - added solution for it.

Comment: actually other column, do not have multiline text, they are with a single values, aplogies that i didnt mention in question, please take a look.

Comment: @silentsudo - Yop, then use last paragraph solution.

Comment: I really appreciate and thank you for the time you are spending, but unfortunately, `post_id column` is still missing after updated with 2nd para solution :'(

Comment: @silentsudo - What is `print (d)` ?

Comment: print d is `{'Date': 'first', 'Comment': <built-in method join of str object at 0x7fcc0a8da8b0>}`

Comment: @silentsudo - Maybe is necessary `df = df.reset_index()` before my solution.

Comment: @silentsudo - Added `print (df.columns)` to answer for test columns labels before applying solution.

Comment: You know what, that `Run All` , I should use frequently and write better code, thank you so much for resolving my query!